# Why is UIView nil after manually instantiating it into mock UIViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, xctest, xctestcase

I am testing my `UiViewController`s with XCUnitTests.

Sometimes I have to mock the `UIViewController` in order to capture a method call. For example whether `performSegue` has been called.

Sometimes one of the methods I test (like `viewDidLoad`) access an IBOutlet. When I create a custom mock subclass and then say `mockViewController.textfield = UITextField()` everything works great.

However, when I want to manually instantiate a `UIView` or a `UIStackView` the variable is still nil, even though the initializer of a `UIView` can never return nil. Why?

Maybe this has something to do with `UIView`s and `UIStackView`s to not have an intrinsic content size? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Just after posting this question I already found the answer.

The reason why my manually instantiated view disappears is that my `@IBOutlet` is a `weak var`. `Weak` simply means, that the variable itself can not keep the instance alive. You need some other variable to keep the instance alive. In my case instead of doing

`mockViewController.stackView = UIStackView()`

I do

`let stackView = UIStackView()
mockViewController.stackView = stackView`

This way the variable `stackView` can keep the instance alive.

Comment: Why don’t you just make your outlet strong?

Comment: I am relatively new to unit testing, but I have been repeatedly told to not write your code differently than when you would not be testing. Never make things public that would be otherwise private and so on.

Comment: Maybe a better argument would be that there is a readon why IBOutlets are weak by default. If I made it strong it would ultimately result in menory and performance issues.

Comment: They are weak by default because Xcode hasn't been updated. Formerly, a view controller would unload its view on a low-memory warning, and weak outlets ensured that the entire view hierarchy could be deallocated. Starting in iOS 6, view controllers no longer unload their views automatically, so there is no longer a reason to make your outlets weak unless you manually unload your view or would otherwise have a retain cycle.

Comment: The latest guidance from Apple was given in WWDC 2015 Session 407, “Implementing UI Designs in Interface Builder”: “In general you should make your outlet strong, especially if you are connecting an outlet to a sub view or to a constraint that's not always going to be retained by the view hierarchy. The only time you really need to make an outlet weak is if you have a custom view that references something back up the view hierarchy and in general that's not recommended.”